# mysq-events multiple watchers bad practice?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I just implented mysql-events to listen for database updates etc.
And now my question is, if it's bad if I listen for 3 databases at once by adding 3 watchers.

```
var watcher1 = mysqlEventWatcher.add(
  'user.db1',
  function (oldRow, newRow, event) {

     //row inserted
    if (oldRow === null) {

    }

     //row deleted
    if (newRow === null) {

    }

     //row updated
    if (oldRow !== null && newRow !== null) {

    }
  });
```

Not sure if there's a better way to listen/watch for multiple databases, I am also not sure if it would be bad if I watch for multiple databases at once, I don't know how mysql-events is listening for changes, maybe short-polling? That's why I'm asking, I don't want to get my mysql server overloaded